# Problem trying to re-use a primary key id with SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to reuse a primary key in one of my tables with SQLAlchemy and am getting foreign key constraint error.

In a nutshell:

- PostgreSQL 8.4
- Python 2.7
- SQLAlchemy 0.7

I have 3 tables: User, Inventories and Devices. Inventories and Devices have a one-to-one relationship with User. User.id is Inventories.user_id and Devices.user_id foreign keyed.

I've got User, Devices and Inventories set up in models/ according to standard python practices.

Within interactive python I can issue the following commands no problem:

```
>>>newUser = User.create()
>>>newUser.device = User.create_device(<*args>)
>>>Session.add(newUser)
>>>Session.commit()
```

(an inventory record is automatically created in code)

Now, let's say I want to re-use User record 1 (it's the only record that will allow a method called reset in code for security and internal testing reasons)

```
>>>oldUser = User.retrieve(1)
>>>Session.delete(oldUser)
>>>Session.commit()
```

(confirm that user 1 no longer exists)

```
>>>newUser = User.create()
>>>newUser.device = User.create_device(<*args>)
>>>newUser.id = 1
>>>Session.add(newUser)
>>>Session.commit()
```

At this point I'll either get an eror that Key(id)=(`<id>`) is still referenced from table "devices" (or "inventories") where `<id>` is the newUser.id before re-assigning it to be id 1

I've looked into cascading and have tried the various options (all, save-update, etc) with no effect.

Any information pointing to where I'm going wrong would greatly be appreciated,

Thanks,

Krys

Answer (score 0):

To address the error you're seeing, you could update the foreign keys on all of the `Device` and `Inventory` models associated with that `User` model before committing. You'll have to make sure that your `User` model doesn't auto-increment the id (i.e., that it isn't a PostgreSQL sequence).

For example, the SQLAlchemy model declaration should be

```
class User(base):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    id = Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True, unique=True, nullable=False)
```

instead of

```
class User(base):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    id = Column('id', Integer, Sequence('user_id_seq'), primary_key=True)
```

BUT, this is probably not the right way to do it! It would be a better design to use a sequence on `User.id` (like in the second model declaration), and add another field on the user table that indicates if the user is an admin (for the security/testing purposes you mentioned). This way you don't have to rely on magic numbers in your application (e.g., the user id) for application logic, especially security.

Answer (score 0):

I ma not using SQLAlchemy, so i do not have a proper answer, but i can say that you must ask yourself what you want is really necessary?

Because,

- You probably will break the data integrity, and that may couse serious problems.
- You will need to break the auto-increment structure of the ID, so until then, you have to assign id's by hand or use a hand-written pre-save trigger to get a proper id.
- If you have tables that have a  **User foreginkey** that sets NOT null, thn you probably will have problem with freeing records related to a deleted user. If you do not null them, a re-used id will create a serious data-integrity problem (wrongly referanced relations)...

So first of all, you must decide if it worth it?

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a problem that shouldn't be seen in production, just use [`SET CONSTRAINTS`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-set-constraints.html). You could use [`INITIALLY DEFERRED`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtable.html) on your `FOREIGN KEY`s but I wouldn't recommend that since you're not dealing with a cyclic dependency that exists in production.